# MSBuild argument containing parameter from target throws error in VSTS

Tags: c#, command-line, build, msbuild, azure-devops

I am running an MSBuild step in my build definition on VSTS which uses Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets and I am passing the OutDir parameter to it as

`/t:Package /p:OutDir="..\artifacts\bin\$(_SGenDllName)\Release\dnx451"`

I am trying to pass the OutDir argument containing a parameter that is valid in Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets, but I get the following error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3963,5): 
Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "C:\agent\_work\2\s\MyApp\artifacts\bin\
                 $(_SGenDllName)\Release\dnx451\MyApp.Api.dll" because it was not found.
```

as it has read `$(_SGenDllName)` literally rather than substituting it for 'MyApp'

So the question is is it possible to pass in an argument to MSBuild that contains a reference to a parameter within the target?

Comment: I thinks that the question is relevant for all batch commands, what about %(_SGenDllName)% as variable?

Comment: `$(_SGenDllName)` is msbuild syntax for expanding properties, the command you show is invoked on the commandline which uses a different syntax and probably won't know what _SGenDllName is anyway. Looked around and your qeustion is basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442883

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use $(SolutionName) in the MsBuild commandline parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442883/use-solutionname-in-the-msbuild-commandline-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [stijn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128384/stijn) pointed out in the comments, using `$(_SGenDllName)` was where I was going wrong.

I swapped that out for `$(TargetName)` and it worked.